# Why does this alternating series converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am given this sequence: $a_n = (-1)^n (n-1)/(n^2 + 4)$.
I was supposed to show that the sum over $a_n$ from $n=1$ to infinity converges.
I wanted to use the Leibniz criterion. However I don't understand why $a_n$ is monotonously decreasing as $a_{n+1}$ is only smaller than $a_n$ for $n > 2$.
I thought it should be decreasing for all values of $n$.
Can someone explain why it doesn't matter that it doesn't for $n < 3$?

I know that if $x_n$ converges then so does $x_{n+k}$ but this doesn't work the other way around, doesn't it?

Thank you!

Comment: $a_n=\frac{(-1)^nn}{n^2+1}+\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2+1}$
Convergence if $\sum_n\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2+1}$ is trivial (in fact one has absolute convergence here); convergence of $\sum\frac{(-1)^nn}{n^2+1}$ is a standard thing since $n\mapsto\frac{n}{n^2+1}$ decreases.

Answer (score 0):

Given any series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ and given any $N\in\Bbb N$, the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges if and only if the series $\sum_{n=N}^\infty a_n$ converges. So, in particular$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n(n-1)}{n^2+4}\text{ converges}\iff\sum_{n=\color{red}3}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n(n-1)}{n^2+4}\text{ converges},$$and this last assertion holds due to the Leibniz test.